# How to properly remove that type of metal to hosepipe lpg seal?

Tags: seal, clio, lpg

Following a crash in the boot while being uninsured, the lpg clio 2 (2008) car of my brother is no longer passing the vehicule inspection test because the chassis is twisted.

Every panel beater I found are requiring to completely remove the untouched lpg gas tank, a 250€ to 300€ operation billed 5 to 6 hours which don t include reassembling costs.

But on factory lpg mounted clios of the time, the tank mounts are in the boot instead of below the car, so I thought I could remove the tank after safely emptying it. [image]
I was able to remove all the mounts and disconnect electric cables in a little over 3 hours instead of the stated 5 hours. The tank can be removed from the boot but not from the car. The remaining thing to do is to disconnect the pipes as unlike what the picture below suggest, the black pipe is the same pipe (I discovered there s a single pipe while trying to split).
[image]
[image]
Does anyone have an idea on how to properly remove that type of soldered seal? I m meaning especially for the black pipe, and more importantly, how to put new ones back?

I noticed such seals can be seen within homes s gas installations, so they don t look to be specifically vehicule related.
What s the required tooling to deal with them?

Comment: It looks to me as though you're looking at the wrong part to remove. To me, the part at the bottom-center of the 2nd image with the blue stripe on it ... this is your junction which should be removed. The part of the hose which is dead center of the 2nd image is a pressure fitting (meaning, it was physically squeezed to stay in position) is meant to be permanent.

Comment: In fact, looking at the first image, it appears the junction to remove is at the other end of elbow which is attached to the part with the blue stripe (I realize both parts have a blue stripe). The part to remove is closer to the tank and should unscrew from the elbow.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, the part your re speaking about cannot be removed without removing the seals first. Because of the second black metal pipe (the one for the gas going into the enigne). I ll details why with a picture tomorrow.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 more exactly, removing the pipe with the blue stripe isn t a problem, but the black pipe is a single pipe going directly from the seal to the valve unlike what the first picture suggest.

Comment: The part with the red ring around it by the tank ... that's what I was talking about. This is where you separate the two. The manufacturer would not have made the setup without a way to get it out. They wouldn't require you to split the pressure fitting to get it apart.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 this isn t what it look on the first picture (third picture added). So apparently, yes, the manufacturer did. I now understand an other reason why mechanics don t want to service this.

Answer (score -1):

I'm glad you added the third photo (2nd in line now) as I think it shows me a view I haven't seen before as well as tells me what you're asking about. Here is my gut reaction on what you need to disassemble.

[image]

At the blue circle, you need to disconnect this fitting from the body of what I would consider to be the regulator (brass looking thing). I'm talking about the silver colored fitting going into the brass. This should free up the thin metal line which you can then (hopefully) fish out of where you need to to get it out of the way.

At the red arrow, you need to separate the silver colored fitting from either the regulator or from the brass elbow. This will allow you to remove the brass elbow from the silver line with (which shares the blue line with the brass elbow).

Again, you should not have to be destructive in any way. This is generally how things automotive are engineered to come apart. While I won't see it's unheard of, I've never seen anything automotive built that way, though I do realize it is sometimes just easier to be destructive and replace the parts (easier/cheaper overall considering man hours add cost). I do not believe this is one of those times.

Comment: Hi, you didn t understand it. Yes I know this but as the black pipe is twisted, removing the second black seal (the one of the dark pipe) is required too. Unlike what is circled in red, there s no junction but a single pipe.

Comment: So while this is a part of the answer this doesn t tell me how to service the type of black seal on the third picture which is also there for the smaller black pipe.